# Why is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) occurring?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

An error is occurring in my Swift app for iOS 8 in Xcode 6.4.

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

Gyazo Screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/6bd9207655763cf941b44c8049f88549.png

I've been trying to fix this error for almost 2 hours now!

Please help me.

Thanks,

Jamie Mathieson

Comment: Have you connected IBOutlets in the storyboard to UsernameTextField? it looks like is not connected.

Comment: @Greg Yup. The IBOutlets are definitely connected in the storyboard to UserNameTextField and the other variables!

Comment: Dont do forced unwrapping like that, use if let binding.

Comment: @nshebbar How do I use if let binding?

Comment: @Bhavin I am entering text into the textfield it's just when I do login, it doesn't work. I don't understand why :(

Comment: @Bhavin Screenshot http://i.gyazo.com/35e5a4835c74cfdc60621a84e2f19ed4.png

Comment: right panel in debug area clearly shows nil...though you enter text...I think you should delete outlets and make a new one for textfield

Comment: I think it's because I use the same outlets for two separate ViewControllers... That's probably why it's not computing the values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a simple problem to solve.. 
UsernameTextField.text and PasswordTextField.text can be blank, so you can't put ! after it..
You have to do something like this:

`if UsernameTextField.text != nil && PasswordTextField != nil {
 user.username = UsernameTextField.text
 user.password = PasswordTextField.text
}`

Hope this helps..